# CSS Grid - Remove extra row at the bottom

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

My goal is to replicate this [mosaic pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2aeG.png) using CSS Grid.  First, I made a div as grid container. Then inside that div, there are five more divs that I used to create the mosaic pattern.

When the `grid-row` of `.grid-item-5` is set to `2 / 3`, the grid container correctly follows the its `grid-template-rows` of `repeat(3, 1fr)`. However, when I tried to complete the pattern by setting the `grid-row` to `2 / 4`, a new blank row appeared at the bottom.

Can somebody help me understand why a blank row appeared and/or how to remove it?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color:hsla(0,0%,92%,1);
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.grid-container {
  background: white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  align-self: center;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #CCCCCC);

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr); 
  grid-gap: 1em; 
}

.grid-container::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  background: teal;
}

.grid-item-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.grid-item-2 {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.grid-item-3 {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

.grid-item-4 {  
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.grid-item-5 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-3">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-4">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-5">5</div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: just remove the `padding-bottom` of `.grid-container::after`

Comment: No worries  Anytime 